# How to access your /home/cpbackuptmp/cpbackup/daily folder cPanel

Tags: mysql, database, backup, cpanel

I am a beginner with cPanel and databases and am having trouble finding the /home/cpbackuptmp/cpbackup/daily folder. I just took over a wordpress site and I was moved to a list where I get emails saying that "[cpbackup] Backup complete on [my site]". In the email it says that the files were backed up to the above location. Where do I go to access this folder? Can I find it through FTP or through the cPanel interface. I do not see it anywhere. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Thanks. I have been looking all day and have not found a good description of where to find the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the both of you. As it turns out, we actually had a backup server where both the daily and weekly backup folders were located.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having root access, First of all check

> Home »Backup »Backup Configuration

From whm. There you can see whether the backups configured as remote ftp or standard.

If its via ftp then there will be the location and ftp credentials

If its via standard , files are backups are stores by default location /backup

/backup can't access by any accounts by cPanel GUI. You need to ssh to the server to see the backups.

Comment: I guess that ia a problem right there, I do not know how to log in to WHM. Was not given the log in credentials. Is it possible for you to explain to me how to execute the standard way? I have searched the entire server and can't find the folder so the second way might be right.

Comment: >http://IP:2086 will get you to WHM log in page. Here you can enter the root password for the server with user as root. In the left side you will see search area. just type "backup" click on "Backup Configuration". Click on enable. This will enable the backups. As you are having dedicated backup server, configure a FTP Destination from the section "Additional Destinations" which is at bottom. Add the ftp credentials. You will see a lot of customization available there. Check what you think is needed and leave others. Let me know if you need any further help

Answer (score 1):

Have you server access, if you have root password then you can login to WHM with username: root and root's password. or login to shell and go to directories /home/cpbackuptmp/cpbackup/daily and check the backup as below:

> cd /home/cpbackuptmp/cpbackup/daily
>
> ls -l